# How to write a multidimensional MS SQL joins to return common, progressive data links

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, identity, common-table-expression

I'm trying to work out an efficient way to identify common data points based on iterative multi-joins. For example:

```
INPUT
-----
ID1 ID2
X   Y
Y   Z
Z   1
A   B
C   D
1   A
B   A
```

X joins to Y. Y joins to Z. Z joins to 1.
Hence, X and 1 are ("common") joined through Y and Z, and so forth, to create the following output:

```
OUTPUT
------
ID1 ID2 CommonKey
X   Y   1
Y   Z   1
Z   1   1
A   B   1
C   D   2
1   A   1
B   A   1
```

If data points are interrelated in any way, current or future, they should be given the same "CommonKey"

I've looked into using CTE's for this solution but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: How to set 2? `C   D   2`? Can you explain?

Comment: "As long as there is a single thread joining the web, they're all joined"

Comment: C and D have no commonalities/ joins to any of the other data points, hence it's assigned the next common key in line = 2

Comment: You can with a `sub query`? Common keys will be 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can with a `WHILE` loop.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Id1 NVARCHAR(10), Id2 NVARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Result TABLE (Id1 NVARCHAR(10), Id2 NVARCHAR(10), CommonKey INT)
DECLARE @RootCounter INT = 1
DECLARE @TempKey NVARCHAR(10)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
('X', 'Y'),     
('Y', 'Z'), 
('Z', '1'), 
('A', 'B'), 
('C', 'D'), 
('1', 'A'), 
('B', '10'),    
('D', '4'), 
('8', '9'), 
('9', 'J'),     
('J', 'R')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RootItems') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RootItems
SELECT
    T.Id1 ,
    T.Id2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS RowId
INTO #RootItems
FROM
    @Tbl T
WHERE
    T.Id1 NOT IN (SELECT I.Id2 FROM @Tbl I)         



WHILE (@RootCounter <= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #RootItems))
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RootTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RootTemp
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CurrTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CurrTemp
    SELECT * INTO #RootTemp FROM #RootItems
    WHERE RowId = @RootCounter

    SELECT Id1,Id2,@RootCounter AS CommonKey INTO #CurrTemp FROM #RootTemp
    INSERT INTO @Result  SELECT * FROM #CurrTemp

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN   

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NextTemp') IS NOT NULL   
            DROP TABLE #NextTemp    

        SELECT Id1,Id2,@RootCounter AS CommonKey INTO #NextTemp FROM @Tbl WHERE Id1 = (SELECT C.Id2 FROM #CurrTemp C)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #CurrTemp C INNER JOIN #NextTemp N ON C.Id1 = N.Id2) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #NextTemp)  BREAK

        INSERT INTO @Result SELECT * FROM #NextTemp
        DELETE FROM #CurrTemp
        INSERT INTO #CurrTemp SELECT * FROM #NextTemp
    END     

     SET @RootCounter += 1                 
END


SELECT * FROM @Result
```

Result:

```
Id1 Id2 CommonKey
X   Y   1
Y   Z   1
Z   1   1
1   A   1
A   B   1
B   10  1
C   D   2
D   4   2
8   9   3
9   J   3
J   R   3
```

Comment: Thanks NER,
How would you scale this

Comment: What do you mean about `scale this`

Comment: If this was a larger data set with multiple groupings for example:
`
('X',   'Y'),
('Y',   'Z'),
('Z',   '1'),
('A',   'B'),
('C',   'D'),
('1',   'A'),
('B',   'A'), 
('D',   '4'),
('8',   '9'),
('9',   'J'),
('8',   'K'),
('J',   'R'), 
`
This has 3 sets

Comment: 8-9 & 9-J have a relation to 8-K, these should all be "3"
Also, D-4 has a relation to C-D and should share a common key

Comment: What you have here is a list of linked lists (pascal terminology), you need to identify the head of each list in a select and then use the CTE to traverse each list. I'm on downtime, if youse haven't solved it by tomorrow, I will elucidate - Cheers

Comment: It works until I add another data row. If I add ('D', 'B') as the 12th row, the code is still returning 3 data groups (3 CommonKey's). With ('D', 'B') added CommonKey 1 and 2 should become the same, resulting in only 2 groupings/ CommonKey's.

Comment: But you cant add `D, B` Because There is  `D, 4` in list. After `C, D` throws  error.

Comment: If I was to add C, D to the list, that combination would then merge CommonKey 1 & 2. I need the code to be able to handle any variation of combinations, is there a way to achieve that? hope this makes sense

Comment: If there is 2 `C, D` in list. You want this in result list too? Or result list has 1 `C, D`?

Comment: I've attached the updated example results above - the code needs to always join common data points. By adding the D, B which connects data points - there are now only 2 groups.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE and adding another 'RowId' to get things in link order:

```
CREATE TABLE  Tbl  (Id1 NVARCHAR(10), Id2 NVARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO Tbl
    VALUES
    ('X', 'Y'),     
    ('Y', 'Z'), 
    ('Z', '1'), 
    ('A', 'B'), 
    ('C', 'D'), 
    ('1', 'A'), 
    ('B', '10'),    
    ('D', '4'), 
    ('8', '9'), 
    ('9', 'J'),     
    ('J', 'R'),
    ('D','B');




 WITH LinkList(Id1,Id2, CommonKey, RowId)
AS
(SELECT Id1, id2, row_number() Over (ORDER BY Id1) AS CommonKey, 1 As RowId FROM tbl WHERE Id1 Not in (select Id2 from tbl)
UNION ALL
 SELECT tbl.id1 as id1 , tbl.id2 as Id2 , LinkList.CommonKey as CommonKey, RowId + 1 as RowId
 FROM tbl 
 INNER JOIN LinkList
    On Linklist.Id2 = tbl.Id1)
    SELECT l.Id1, l.Id2 , l.CommonKey, k.MinKey, ISNULL (k.Minkey, l.CommonKey) AS NewCommonKey
    FROM LinkList l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT x.CommonId, X.CommonKey, y.MinKey FROM 
    (SELECT Min(Id2) AS CommonId, CommonKey FROM LinkList WHERE ID2 IN
    (SELECT Id2
    FROM LinkList 
    GROUP BY Id2
    Having Count(CommonKey) > 1) 
    GROUP BY CommonKey) as X CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(CommonKey) as MinKey FROM LinkList WHERE Id2 = x.CommonId) AS y) AS k
    ON l.CommonKey = k.CommonKey    

    DROP Table Tbl
```

Result Is:

```
Id1 Id2 CommonKey   MinKey  NewCommonKey
8   9   1   NULL    1
C   D   2   2   2
X   Y   3   2   2
Y   Z   3   2   2
Z   1   3   2   2
1   A   3   2   2
A   B   3   2   2
B   10  3   2   2
D   4   2   2   2
D   B   2   2   2
B   10  2   2   2
9   J   1   NULL    1
J   R   1   NULL    1
```

It needs another select and group wrapped around it to get rid of the duplicates,
but you can see the list being merged this way, pardon my formatting skills.
Is that what you're after?

Comment: Similar to the solution below - It works until I add another data row. If I add ('D', 'B') as the 12th data row, the code is still returning 3 data groups (3 CommonKey's). With ('D', 'B') added, CommonKey 1 and 2 should become the same, resulting in only 2 groupings/ CommonKey's.

Comment: Ok I treated the data as linked lists, you should have included the ('D', 'B') option in your example data :-) . The next step would be to combine list with common rows. Shouldn't be too hard, I'll get back to you.

Comment: That should be scalable as well now

Comment: Thanks MikeAinOz! I tried editing your response above with comments, did that come through to you? This is looking really good!

Comment: This example is more simple, it should return only 3 groups, but for some reason returns 4? /*Set1*/ ('1', '2'),('2', '3') /*Set2*/ ,('B', 'C') ,('A', 'B') /*Set3*/ ,('FF', 'GA'),('FZ', 'GA'),('FF', 'GG')

Comment: Yeah it's that 'FF', 'GG' combo there's no join of id1 to id1 to detect this and 'GG' id2 has no match. Suggest you write the output to a temp table and then process again for that match. I'm sure you can manage this yourself ;-).